# Th linq query could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated .NETCore

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I have a query as you can see here :

```
 public Domain.PetrolReceptions.PetrolReception GetLastOpenNotCanceledByVIN(string vin,
            double openPetrolTestTimeInDays)
            => _dbContext.PetrolReceptions.Where(g =>
                g.Car.carBody.vin == vin && g.CreatedDate.AddDays(openPetrolTestTimeInDays) >= DateTime.Today && g.Status != Domain.PetrolReceptions.PetrolReception.PetrolReceptionStatus.Canceled_Passed && g.Status != Domain.PetrolReceptions.PetrolReception.PetrolReceptionStatus.Canceled_Failed && g.Status != Domain.PetrolReceptions.PetrolReception.PetrolReceptionStatus.Canceled_Pending).OrderBy(g => g.CreatedDate).LastOrDefault();
```

When I want to execute this code by running my visual i get this error :

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<PetrolReception>
    .Where(p => p.Car.carBody.vin == __vin_0 && p.CreatedDate.AddDays(__openPetrolTestTimeInDays_1) >= DateTime.Today && (int)p.Status != 5 && (int)p.Status != 4 && (int)p.Status != 3)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply AddDays to the parameter, not the column expression.

Change

```
g.CreatedDate.AddDays(openPetrolTestTimeInDays) >= DateTime.Today
```

to

```
var endDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1 * openPetrolTestTimeInDays);
. . .
g.CreatedDate <= endDate
```